# Taylor of $\ln(f(exp(x))))$?

Tags: analysis, logarithms, exponential-function, taylor-expansion, parameter-estimation

Let $ f(x) = \sum a_n x^n$ Such that
The $a_n$ are real and $f(a),f ' (a) , f " (a) > 0 $ for any real $a > 0$.

Let $ \ln(f(exp(x))) = \sum b_n x^n $.

Let $c_n = a_n - b_n$.

For a given $f$ and a given $y$ When is it true that $c_n ^2 < (y / n )^2$ (for every n) and how to prove this ?

Comment: I know faa di Bruno , but not sure how that helps.

Comment: You postulate that series $\sum b_n x^n$ exists?  I do not see how it follows from the other assumptions.

Comment: @GEdgar : notice that $f(0) > 0 , exp(0)=1 $and $f(1) > f(0)$. Therefore $\ln(f(exp(0))) $ exists and thus we have a Taylor series. At least a formal one. The radius is another matter, but that relates to the coëfficiënts ofcourse.

Comment: I also know Carleman matrices , but again I do not know how and if that helps.

Comment: Maybe if we consider $f$ as a polynomial first ?